# Cannot start SQLEXPRESS service

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2022, localdb

I'm using `Visual Studio 2022` and with `EF 6.0.12` I'm trying a code first approach to create a database schema.

I've installed `SQL SERVER EXPRESS 2019 LocalDB` with Visual Studio Installer and it is showed on the individual components list.

Using SQL Server Object Explorer I tried to connect to `MSSQQLLocalDB` which has appeared in the list.

```
ServerName: (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
Authentication: Windows Authentication
```

But when I clicked on connect this error appears:

> ### TITLE: Error
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
> Errore durante l'avvio dell'istanza di Local DB: avvio del processo di
> SQL Server non riuscito. ) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1983577846)

**WHAT I'VE TRIED SO FAR:**

1. I've run `services.msc`, selected SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service and checked ```Local System Account" under Log On and tried to start manually the service.

**Output: ERROR 1067: The process terminated unexpetctedly**

2. Using SQL server configuration manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols for SQLEXPRESS I've enabled the TCP/IP option and set IpAll -> TCP PORT to 1433.

But after a restart the service is not starting.

3. I've tried to uninstall SQL SERVER EXPRESS LOCALDB 2019 with Visual Studio and manually install it downloading from the Windows website.

But the installation crashed and in the log folder I found this:

```
2023-01-11 19:46:21.42 spid10s     There have been 256 misaligned log IOs which required falling back to synchronous IO.  The current IO is on file C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS01\MSSQL\Template Data\master.mdf.
```

Tbh I think my system is far beyond the requirements, so I really don't get why I have encountered so many problems for a simple local installation.

---

EDIT:

THis is the log from the Event Viewer

> Faulting application name: sqlservr.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp:
> 0x00000000 Faulting module name: unknown, version: 0.0.0.0, time
> stamp: 0x00000000 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset:
> 0x00007fffc3bf0093 Faulting process id: 0x0x3B08 Faulting application
> start time: 0x0x1D925FC511425F6 Faulting application path: C:\Program
> Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe
> Faulting module path: unknown Report Id:
> 48180913-b884-47ae-9396-470014ebcbc4 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

EDIT 2:

**fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo C:** command result

```
LogicalBytesPerSector :                                 512
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity :                    4096
PhysicalBytesPerSectorForPerformance :                  16384
FileSystemEffectivePhysicalBytesPerSectorForAtomicity : 4096
Device Alignment :                                      Aligned (0x000)
Partition alignment on device :                         Aligned (0x000)
No Seek Penalty
Trim Supported
Not DAX capable
Not Thinly-Provisioned
```

**PARTIALLY RESOLVED :**

I've installed SQL SERVER on another memory.

The original memory was a ***Crucial P2 CT500P2SSD8 SSD***

Comment: When you try to start the service and it fails, read the event logs; what do those say?

Comment: If you open a Command Prompt and run `fsutil fsinfo sectorinfo C:` what's the output? Sounds like the C: drive of your system is using a sector size that's not compatible with SQL Server 2019. Ref: [Troubleshoot errors related to system disk sector size greater than 4 KB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/database-file-operations/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size).